# Which header file is to be used for datetime programs?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

This program is giving error that symbol cannot found in almost all the lines. I have used `import java.io.*` and `java.util.*`. Is there any other header file to be used?

```
String s = br.readLine();
String s1 = br.readLine();
DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/mm/yyyy");//error
DateTime start = dt.parseDateTime(s);//error
DateTime end = dt.parseDateTime(s1);//error
int ctr =0;
DateTime date = start.withDayOfMonth(13);//error
if(date.compareTo(start)==-1)
{
    start = start.plusMonths(1);//error
}
while(start.isBefore(end))
{
    DateTime date = start.withDayOfMonth(13);
    if(date.getDayOfWeek()==DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY)
    {
        ctr++;
    }
    start = start.plusMonths(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you obviously refer to Joda-Time, too. So you need these imports:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;
```

Or better without star-imports:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import static org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY;
```

Comment: @KeshavRastogi Then please ensure that your Joda-Time-library you are referring to exists in your class path. However, this issue is not related to programming but about how to set up your programming environment (IDE configuration, installation of external libraries etc.).